# Fusion Charts for representing data in graphical form

Tags: json, web-services, pie-chart, fusioncharts

I am trying to render my data in a graph using fusion charts. I have a web service that returns the data in JSON format. I want to render chart for that data. can I directly give the URL of my web service so that I cannot set key value pairs. Is it possible to do so/ Can any one please tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It can use a JSON URL/feed, a JSON Object (in JavaScript) or JSON String. This functionality is provided by FusionCharts class method `setJSONUrl()`. Example

```
myChart.setJSONUrl("Data.json");
```

See http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/FirstChart/JSONData.html

Answer (score -1):

FusionCharts Suite has a specific JSON structure for each category of charts. While passing the data to render method, data is expected in the pre defined format. Please refer to: http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/DataFormats/JSON/Overview.html

Comment: My Web services return data in the following format                  [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "dateTime": "Mar 15, 2014 10:50:55 AM",
        "Name": "John",
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "dateTime": "Mar 25, 2014 10:50:55 AM",
        "Name": "Tom",
    }                                                               ]                                                                                    How can I directly give my url and generate a chart? can u please tell me how to do this

Comment: Try using "setChartDataUrl" function and set it to the URL of your web serices. Eg.myChart.setChartDataUrl("mydynamicdata.aspx", "json");    For information on this function refer: http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/index.html?JavaScript/API/Methods.html#setchartdataurl  Also, make sure that your JSON confirms to the format that FusionCharts accepts.